# Why are (1) “If A, then B.” and (2) (not A) or B "essentially identical"? Is my understanding correct?

Tags: logic

Read this in a book that (1) and (2) are "in essence, identical"...

As I understand, (1) is proven "false" only when A doesn't imply B (Hypothesis is True but Conclusion False). It stands true for all other (the following) cases:

```
| Hypothesis (A) | Conclusion (B) |
|----------------|----------------|
| True           | True           |
| False          | True           |
| False          | False          |
```

Below is the Truth Table for (2)

```
| A    | B    | (not A) or B |
|------|------|--------------|
| True | True | True         |
| True | False| False        |
| False| True | True         |
| False| False| True         |
```

So, since both (1) and (2) are False only when A is True and B is False, they are "logical equivalents". But does that make them "essentially identical"? If yes, why? If not, why?

Comment: They are [logical equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) because they have the same truth table. Maybe "essentially identical" is not the right word.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, the textbook author could have been getting at how it's used? In terms of usage it is special. I'm not a fan of the terminology either, though

Comment: Your intuition is right. In a sense, "A implies B" is just a "shorter" or "more intuitive" form of saying "not A or B"

Answer (score 2):

It is not obvious why $A\to B$ should be equivalent to $\lnot A\lor B$ but it is not hard to prove. We say that $A\to B$ if $B$ is true whenever $A$ is.

Suppose $A\to B$ is true.

In propositional logic any statement is either true or false so $\lnot A\lor A$ is always true. By our hypothesis, whenever $A$ is true, $B$ is true so, by substitution, $\lnot A\lor B$ is true.

Suppose $\lnot A\lor B$ is true.

We want to show that $B$ is true whenever $A$ is true so suppose that $A$ is true. Then $\lnot A$ is false but $\lnot A\lor B$ is true so $B$ must be true. Therefore, $A\to B$ is true.

Answer (score 2):

(In general) $(A)\Rightarrow (B)$ is an abbreviation for $(\lnot A)   \lor (B)$. They denote essetially the same thing.
Now we can ask ourselves why we would define the notion of implication this way and there i can refer to the above below my answer.. or to any introductory textbook on mathematics(for example Kevin Houstons book called: How to think like a mathematician).

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, those two compound propositions are logically equivalent (in other words, they are tautologically equivalent).

In plain language: whatever meaning I assign to $A$ and $B$ (for example, they might respectively mean "Paris is in France" and "Qatar is in Australia"), both compound propositions have matching truth values.

In other words, $$\text{those two propositions are, in essence, identical},$$ as the  author has *informally* (and ambiguously/questionably) asserted.