# Is this a correct interpretation of P implies q?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Based on the truth table definition of P implies q, I have been thinking of it saying that not only "we gaurantee that Q is true when P is true", but also as explicitly saying that  "if P is false, q can be either true or false". My question is because my class notes say that P implies Q doesn't say anything whatsoever in the case of P being false, only gaurantee the truth of Q given P. (They explain the last two rows in the truth table by saying because P implies q says nothing, we don't hold it to account). However, I was wondering if we could imagine it as explicitly saying P could be either truth value when P is false, contrary to my class notes. I was would appreciate feedback on whether this is in accordance with how an experienced mathematician would interpret this statement.

Edit: after a comment mentioned that the law of excluded middle is applicable for saying q can be either true or false , I would like to also ask here if this is a proper justification behind thinking of P implies q as also saying q can be either true or false if P is false, as the law of excluded middle is a different concept than p implies q- does p implies q make any statement as to the law of excluded middle?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your statement is true. In other words, if you know that $P \implies q$ and $P$ is false, then you can't say anything about the logic value of $q$ (i.e., $q$ can be either true or false).

Comment: The truth table has four rows. Your first statement correctly describes the first two, and your second statement correctly describes the last two.

Comment: @xyz is not saying anything about q when P is false identical to explicitly saying that it can be either true or false, though? In the one case we refrain from saying anything about q, in the other case we make a statement about q that it must assume either true or false. Is this covered by the law of excluded middle anyway, so P implies q is not actually the one who says it ?

Comment: The law of the excluded middle tells you that for every propostion, either this proposition is true or its negation is true. This is exactly the same as saying that every proposition is either True or False. Therefore, the statements "you can't say anything about the logical value of $q$" and "$q$ can be either True or False" coincide. As for your last question, the answer is yes. If $P$ is false, the implication $P \implies q$ doesn't tell you anything about $q$.

Comment: @xyz however, would we attribute the law of excluded middle to p implies q? P implies q doesn't say anything about the law of excluded middle, so for that reason, is it the case that P implies q doesn't say that Q can be either true or false when p is false, even though we know that this is so?

Comment: @God if you want to formulate the law of excluded middle via propositional logic it would be that $p \lor \lnot{p}$ always has a truth value (aka tautology). But $p \implies q$ doesn't always have a truth value, they are not equivalent.

Comment: @Amit so this would mean that it is not correct to think of P implies q as communicating "if P is false, q can be either true or false" due to the law of excluded middle? The only justification hereof is the truth table?

Comment: @Amit how is it the case that P implies q doesn't always have a truth value?

Comment: @God Example: $T \implies F$ has a false value. ($T$ stands for truth value, $F$ for a false value). Propositional logic deals with the assignment of truth via logical relationships, *not* with whether propositions are true or not... the truth and falseness of logical formulas depends upon the truth/false values *you* assign to your propositions

Comment: @God *Any* proposition is either true or false, that is essentially an axiom, it is not a consequence of the truth table of the implication operation

Comment: I wouldn't be switching between lower-case and upper-case letters because it's a little confusing. If you want to represent a statement by a letter, you would have to put the dollar signs around them, as you can see in a Mathjax tutorial.

Comment: @amit sorry, I meant truth value in the sense a value which is either true or false, a value which makes a statement as to the truth of something

Comment: @God So I don't know what you're asking / what you don't understand about what I already wrote

Comment: @Amit, sorry my question is though the law of the excluded middle and p implies q are not logically equivalent , could interpreting p implies q as saying "if P is false, q is either true or false" be correct from the standpoint of regarding p implies q as being cognizant of the law of the excluded middle in saying q is either true or false here in this case?

Comment: @God I'm trying to say that even if $p$ is true, $q$ can be false!! :) Just writing down a logical formula $p \implies q$ tells you *nothing* about the value of either $p$, $q$ or $p \implies q$ as a whole. It's completely *legitimate* to set $p$ as true, $q$ as false and then *correctly* assign $p \implies q$ a false value, as the truth table indeed instructs us to. So the statement that "if $p$ is false we have no information about $q$" has no meaning. Perhaps you mean to say "if $p$ is false *and* we know that $p \implies q$ is *true* then $q$ can either be false or true"....

Comment: ... but this would just be restating two lines (when $p$ is false) of the truth table of the $\implies$ operation in different words. This is *not* in some fundamental way the reason that the law of excluded middle was chosen to be an axiom.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking if the statement "if $P$ is false, then $Q$ is either true or false" is equivalent to the law of excluded middle? If you want to get a better understanding of implication statements in logic, it's probably better to think of $P \implies Q$ as a promise that whenever $P$ is true, $Q$ will be true also. There's only one way that promise would break, which is when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. (E.G. maybe try constructing a truth table of the statement "If you pass the final, then you will pass the course.")

Comment: @Amit what is the reason why we need to know P implies Q is true to say that Q can be either true or false when  P is false? P implies Q is never false when P is false.

Comment: @God Yes, that's a special property of the implication operation. I was only however trying to emphasize that in writing down the formula we don't necessarily assume it is true yet. For the case of implication however that's right, if the left side happens to be false we know its value immediately as we write it down :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are (1) “If A, then B.” and (2) (not A) or B "essentially identical"? Is my understanding correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234167/why-are-1-if-a-then-b-and-2-not-a-or-b-essentially-identical-is-my)

Comment: I just don't understand why you signal out the implication operator in being "cognizant of the law of excluded middle"... if you look at the definition / truth table of any logical operator, you'll see that the only values considered are true and false, *and no third option* :) So the entire structure of propositional logic is cognizant of it, this is nothing particular to the implication operator.

Comment: @Amit does this mean if a proposition doesn't say anything about the truth value of one of its variables, it essentially is averring that this variable can be either true or false?

Comment: @God Exactly! Only a slight correction is that you are talking about the operations. Logical operations like $\implies$ , $\land$, etc. don't say anything about whether its variables are true/false as you mean to say. Then when we want to assign values to these operations we have to assign values to the variables, and we use the truth table of the operation to figure out what value it will obtain according to the values of the variables, that's why operations are useful, because they *don't* always obtain the same value.

Answer (score 2):

An example may help to understand the truth table here. Consider the the implication:

If it is raining, then it is cloudy.

$~~~~~~R\implies C$

This does not mean that rain *causes* cloudiness. Or that, *historically*, it has always been cloudy when it was raining. Or that cloudiness is somehow "provable" from the fact that it is raining.

It means only that, at the moment, it is not both raining and not cloudy.

$~~~~~~R\implies C ~~\equiv ~~\neg (R \land \neg C)$

This "definition" is entirely consistent with the truth table, e.g if $R$ is false and $C$ is true (line 3), then both $R \implies C$ and $\neg (R \land \neg C)$ will be true.

$~~~~~~~~ R~~~~C~~~~~~R\implies C~~~~~\neg(R \land \neg C)$

$1.~~~~T~~~~T~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T$

$2.~~~~T~~~~F~~~~~~~~~~~~~~F~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~F$

$3.~~~~F~~~~T~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T$

$4.~~~~F~~~~F~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~T$

---

**Note the Following**

- Rule of Detachment: If $R$ is true and $R\implies C$ is true, then $C$ must also be true
  (line 1 only)
- Principle of Vacuous Truth: If $R$ is false, then $R\implies C$ must be true, regardless of the
  truth value of $C$ (lines 3, 4)
- If $C$ is true, then $R\implies C$ must be true, regardless of the
  truth value of $R$ (lines 1, 3)